# Cslider autoplay is not working when I try to apply for two ID's(divs)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using `Cslider` in my parallax design , I liked it alot ,but I strucked with this when about apply cslider for 2 instances(for 2 different divs) , this is working fine when I try to apply for 1 instance(1 div). what I want is I need to apply cslider autoplay true for 1 div and cslider autoplay false for another div ,just like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $('#div1').cslider({
    autoplay    : false

     });

    $('#div2').cslider({
    autoplay    : true,
    bgincrement : 450
     });

});

</script>
```

My Html Code :

```
<div id="div1" class="da-slider">
    <div class="da-slide">
    <h2>Some description</h2>
    <p>Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description</p>
    <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
        <div class="da-img"><img src="css/slider/images/2.png" alt="image01" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="da-slide">
    <h2>Some description</h2>
    <p>Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description Some description</p>
    <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
        <div class="da-img"><img src="css/slider/images/2.png" alt="image01" /></div>
        </div>  

     <nav class="da-arrows">
    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
    <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
     </nav>
</div>  




 <div id="div2" class="da-slider" style="height:270px;">
      <div class="da-slide">
         <div class="scrollyeah" data-centerIfFit="true">
         <div class="item1">
               <a class="vlightbox3" href="images/01.jpg" >
                 <img src="images/img01.gif" />
               </a>
            </div>
             <div class="item1">
               <a class="vlightbox3" href="images/01.jpg" >
                 <img src="images/img01.gif" />
               </a>
            </div>
          </div>
       <h5>Scroll through all of the screenshots of the website and admin backend above</h5>
     </div>

     <div class="da-slide">
         <div class="scrollyeah" data-centerIfFit="true">
         <div class="item1">
               <a class="vlightbox3" href="images/01.jpg" >
                 <img src="images/img01.gif" />
               </a>
            </div>
             <div class="item1">
               <a class="vlightbox3" href="images/01.jpg" >
                 <img src="images/img01.gif" />
               </a>
            </div>
          </div>
       <h5>Scroll through all of the screenshots of the website and admin backend above</h5>
     </div>
     <nav class="da-arrows">
    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
        <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>      
      </nav>
  </div>
```

here in my case div1 is not working . but When I set both div cslider `autoplay` option to `true` then those are working fine.

Can anyone please help me .

Comment: Yes, we can help. But I have to say my **psychic powers** aren't working today, and you probably have some hard-set `variable` in the `source` that is determining this. Care to provide some code? I have the feeling you are calling the same `class` or `id` for the second slideshow.

Comment: @ratnakar Can you please post the cslider plugin url ?

Comment: @dhan this is the plugin documentation I used

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: @NicholasHazel , pls review the code I updated question

Comment: Call your function `inline` with your `body` after each `DOM` element of `class="da-slider"` gets loaded, as in RIGHT before the next `da-slider` element.

Comment: @NicholasHazel  I tried but no use ...

Comment: May have to modify your plugin unfortunately. `plugins` are easy for a reason, and if they didn't build a `repeat` function, you're at the mercy of hard coding it yourself.

Comment: @NicholasHazel ... When I set those slider autoplay to true its working fine .. But when I set one as false my navigation arrows are behaving like un-clickable

Comment: Right, something in the deeper code is causing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are said that `autoplay:true` is working but when you put the `autoplay:false` it is not working right ?. I think your next and prev events are not cliking.Ok, In this case you have two outputs,

1. Some divs are overlapping your nav buttons.
2. You got any errors in the browser console.

Try to inspect the html code or find the errors in console.

Comment: hey its working man .. yes my slider first div is having overlapped with nav bars... I added z-index for this .. its strange to me .. I did not expect this issue related with this problem .. anyhow got fixed .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### So, here is my take on the subject:

You have a `slider`, taken externally, that won't perform multiple `instances` on the same page, correct?

Well, with `CSS`, you can modify whatever you want for a single property, but the `JS` will always take effect after the fact.

The reason you are encountering the same `properties` being `inherited` is likely because the `JS` file is obtaining those from your last call to it.

To create a `plugin` for a need it wasn't intended for (no support for `multiple instances`) you would need to `hard-code` your plugin to accept multiple values. I don't believe there is any `CSS hack` you could implement if your `plugin` is taking precedence.

**I know it's not the answer you want to hear, but unfortunately it's true.**

The only real recourse is to remap your plugin, or write `JS` that will counteract it and load it at the base of your `body`.